How to prevent consequences of code execution in try block if exception is raised?
I want to prevent execution on try block if it raises an Exception of any kind. Example:
a = 1
try:
    a += 1
    raise ValueError
except:
    pass
print(a)

After that a would be equal to 2. I want it to remain 1. In that particular case I could add a -=1 into except block, but that is not a solution for more complex stuff. Is there a way to do that smoothly?

Create a variable to add to a at the end of the try block?

There's no generic solution, no. A try block can't magically undo any code that's been running. That would be entirely unreasonable. What if some external file got created or contents got written somewhere or external API calls have been made? How would it delete and uncall all that automagically?

If your code were updating a database, you could use a transaction which got rolled back in the event of an exception. In general code, there's no way.

The behavior you are looking for is called a transaction, and is typically provided by a database: you specify a series of modifications which get applied to a "copy" of the database, and if any of them fail then none of the them are applied to the "real" database.

There is a concept of software transactional memory, but try statements do not implement that.

You have multiple abstract cases :

The raising code is independent from environment modifying code. In this case, check first, then make changes after, so if it fails, the environment is not changed yet.
The environment changes depend on the possibly raising code. To do it safely, you should save those changes temporarily, and once every step is validated (end of your try block), apply them. So that, if anything bad happens, you did not apply environment modification yet, and it remains unchanged (or you can even choose to partially apply them).
The raising code actually makes environment changes. If it is your code, it is your responsibility to make so that an error restores the environment as it was before it happened. If it is distant code, it is its maintainer responsibility not to both change the system state and produce an error, which would be an undefined behavior from your pov.

These are the cases I can think of at the moment.
